# Will Strings logged in loop pollute memory?

Tags: java, memory

consider code:

```
while(true) {
  System.out.println("Current time: " + System.nanoTime());
}
```

Will this code pollute memory with strings? My app should print such log in loop for 5-10 hours into console.

Answer (score 4):

The memory will be garbage collected and therefore should not be a concern.

If you're going to redirect the console output into a file, it might be worth thinking about how large the file will grow and whether there's enough disk space to accommodate it.

Comment: To add more detail-  each iteration of the loop will create one new string, but it will be eligible for collection immediately after the println returns.  If you were doing things on another thread simultaneously, you may cause some fragmentation, but it isn't really a worry.